# Load testing tool has "redirect" http request

Tags: performance, http, testing, load

I am testing the load for my application.
It is an application writing by Go. But in my application, It need to redirect between containers (leader and follower mechanism) using HTTP status code 3xx (`http.Redirect(abc, xyz, url, 307)`)

For `curl`, I can use `-L` option.

I want to find a load testing tool (like apache benchmark) but it will have the redirect option which the same with `-L` option in `curl`.

Someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try JMeter, See HTTP Request Sampler and the settings 'Redirect Automatically' and 'Follow Redirects'

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request